# SQL Inner join with function returning table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder if the following is possible.

I have a SQL function that splits a coma separated string returning a table with the splited values.

hello,my name,is,John

returns a table:

```
ITEM
-----
hello
my name
is
John
```

A have a table storing, for each row, an ID and a coma separated string:

```
VALUE_TO_SPLIT
--------------
1 | a,b,c
1 | d,e,f,g
2 | a,b
3 | a
3 | b,c,f
```

Without using cursors, is it possible to obtain the resulting table?

```
RESULTING_TABLE
1 | a
1 | b
1 | c
1 | d
1 | e
1 | f
1 | g
2 | a 
2 | b
3 | a  
3 | b  
3 | c  
3 | f
```

That is, a rows for each splited value with its id.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please stop tagging with both; they're *different*.

Comment: even if it is possible, it is usually done with languages that have better support for processing strings

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function *looks* like an inline table-valued function; if you can include the function we can also suggest whether it is an efficient implementation ([not all are](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)).

```
SELECT t.col, s.Item
FROM dbo.tablename AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.function_name(t.value) AS s;
```

You should also consider not storing separate values as comma-separated lists in the first place. A database table should not be a JSON container, IMHO.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks. About storing coma-separated lists in the database, totally agree, but it is inherited from previous developers :)